# setting a time delay between two frame when animation a sprite sheet

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery

this is my jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a5h/

As you can see the animation of the sprite sheet when the player is not moving is too fast so i was trying to make it slow by declaring two variable `lastRenderTime: 0,RenderRate: 50000`

but my code is not working and it seem i have a misunderstanding of the algorithm i am using so can anyone lay me a hand to how can i fix it ?

```
 if (!this.IsWaiting) {
                    this.IsWaiting = true;
                    this.Pos = 1 + (this.Pos + 1) % 3;

                }
                else {
                    var now = Date.now();
                    if (now - this.lastRenderTime < this.RenderRate) this.IsWaiting = false;
                    this.lastRenderTime = now;

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your code.

Firstly, you update the `lastRenderTime` at each iteration so `now - this.lastRenderTime` has always more or less the same value (the time between now and the last iteration).
Your assignation (`this.lastRenderTime = now`) should be inside your `if` brackets.

Secondly, you're doing your comparison the wrong way. you should check if the time since the last image change is greater than your `RenderRate`: `now - this.lastRenderTime >= this.RenderRate` but you're doing the opposite.

Due to these issues, your condition is always true and, then, the image changes at every single iteration.

Comment: thank you for your answer could you please update my jsfiddle please

Comment: Meh, that's not how it works / is interesting / is constructive. I think my points are quite clear. If not I'll be glad to explain some more. But just fix/debug code in a fiddle isn't the right way.

Comment: Third problem: the modern preferred way to update at a regular interval is [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)  @Sora although it's not against the rules to ask, please don't demand a jsfiddle update in order to vote this as the answer to question.  SE isn't a fiddle-correction machine, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: You're right for `window.requestAnimationFrame`. That is not something making the code *don't work*  though.

Comment: well i tried to fix the issue but my problem remain this is my update : http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a5h/3/

Comment: Well, you did fix the second point I raised. For, on the other side, take a look at your code. You're assigning `this.lastRenderTime` to a variable named `now` that does not exist at this time. Think of **when the *last time the image changed* should be updated ?**. That should be at the same time you say you're no *waiting* anymore.

Comment: Done :D Thank you so much : http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a5h/4/

Comment: Also, this is the kind of behavior that should not be handled in your *entity* but in some kind of *manager*.

Comment: what do you mean ?